# file_get_contents("php://input" returns empty string

Tags: php, json

i have a request class which should get the post json data

```
class Request
{
    public $data;

    public function __construct ( )
    {
        $this->data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    }
}
```

when i perform a `print_r($this->data)`, the `print_r()` is emtpy, when i perform a `var_dump()` the content is displayed as it should

that's what I sent as POST request to the server

```
{"currentFilter": {"groupSelect":"all","hostSelect":"all","prioritySelect":"all","priorityOf":"none","priorityTo":"none","periodSelect":"all","periodDateStart":"none","periodDateEnd":"none","messageFilter":"none"},"firstseq":null,"lastseq":null}
```

what I'm doing wrong that I get a empty string

the difference is between the browser firefox and chrome

```
class ResultController extends Controller
{

    public function loadLogs ( )
    {
         $this->prepareRequest();
    }

    public function prepareRequest ( )
    {
     print_r($this->request->data);
     var_dump($this->request->data);
    }
```

in chrome i get the array and in firefox i get just null

clientside code

```
load : function ( ) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var currentFilter = FilterModel.getCurrentFilter();

    var data = {
        'currentFilter' : currentFilter,
        'firstseq' : LogsController.firstseq,
        'lastseq' : LogsController.lastseq
    };

    var url = 'php/main.php?controller=Result&action=loadLogs';

    server.post(url, data).done(function ( data ) {
        LogsController.firstseq = data.firstelem;
        LogsController.lastseq = data.lastelem;
        LogsView.appendLogs(data.resultdata);
        view.setPriorityColor();
        deferred.resolve();
    }).fail(function ( textStatus ) {
        view.popupError(textStatus.responseText);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
},
```

Comment: Why are you not using `$_POST` instead of `file_get_contents("php://input")` ?

Comment: And what do you get when you perform `echo print_r($_POST,true);` ?

Comment: @RichardBernards Because when you post something like JSON, `$_POST` will not be populated.

Comment: @RichardBernards Because in this case he's simply posting the JSON (without any `key=val` statements) to the server. For all you know he's building a webservice to replace an already implemented one. OP: Have you tried to `var_dump( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) )`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `print_r()` is empty but `var_dump()` isn't; could you put together the exact code that you're using?

Comment: If the difference is with the browser, it's probably not with PHP :)

Comment: @Jack I send both times in firefox and in chrome the same data, I can see it also in the request section, but the output of each browser is different... i suspect that there is an error with php://input

Comment: after I build an mysql query, which works in chrome and in firefox not... when I send the standart params the where statement should be empty (it is in chrome but not in firefox) the where statement in firefox is not empty ... because in the code I check if the params are like the currentfilter params i posted in my question

Comment: Now there's MySQL involved? Your question should contain the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue; and since the behaviour is different for each browser, perhaps you should share the client side code as well ... also, I'm seriously hoping you're looking at the page source and not the rendered page.

Comment: Where's `server.post()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

`php://input` can be read once only. You will need to save the result somewhere and access that

> : Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be
>   read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However,
>   depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open
>   another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible
>   if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case
>   for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or
>   PROPFIND.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: I save the result to $this->data

Comment: and the seocnd object you access it in ? It needs to be somewhere static really which exists across all instances